# Check if an embed already exists in a list of stored embeds sent by my bot

Tags: python, discord.py

Im new to programming was creating a discord bot. I have a bot that can take quotes from a user and save them, and then send each quote that the bot has saved. However the problem is people can keep giving in the same quote and flood the list. And when they ask for the list of quotes it sends the same quotes over and over again. How can I check if an embed already exists within the list of embeds? I tried if em in em_list and the problem is that each embed is given a unique value, even if its the same information. Heres my code below

```
@client.command(aliases=['save'],brief='quote a user')
async def quote(ctx,user:discord.Member,*,message):
    color=discord.Color(value=0x9C2A00)
    async for messages in ctx.channel.history(limit=1):
        pass
    em=discord.Embed(color=color,title=message,description=f'-{user}, [original](https://discordapp.com/channels/{messages.guild.id}/{messages.channel.id}/{messages.id})')
    await ctx.send(em_list)
    em_list.append(em)



@client.command(aliases=['getsaves','getquotes'],brief='gets last quote/unfinished command')
async def getquote(ctx):
     for quote in em_list:
         await ctx.send(embed=quote)
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: Save a list of strings and check against that instead.

Comment: Hey! Thank you! What do you mean save a list of strings? @PatrickHaugh

Comment: Instead of comparing a new embed to a list of saved embeds, compare the candidate quote to a list of saved quotes.  Alternatively, you could use [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) to check against the `description` of each of your saved embeds: `if quote in map(attrgetter('description'), em_list):`