# Checking if an embed already exists in a list of stored embeds sent by my bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I am new to programming and created a discord bot which can store a 'quote' embed by a user in a list. The problem is that I dont want to store duplicates of these quotes.
Im not sure how to check if the embed is already in my em_list, because each embed is unique even if the content in it is a duplicate. Please help :((

```
@client.command(aliases=['save'],brief='quote a user')
async def quote(ctx,user:discord.Member,*,message):
    color=discord.Color(value=0x9C2A00)
    async for messages in ctx.channel.history(limit=1):
        pass
    em=discord.Embed(color=color,title=message,description=f'-{user}, [original](https://discordapp.com/channels/{messages.guild.id}/{messages.channel.id}/{messages.id})')
    await ctx.send(em_list)
    em_list.append(em)



@client.command(aliases=['getsaves','getquotes'],brief='gets last quote/unfinished command')
async def getquote(ctx):
     for quote in em_list:
         await ctx.send(embed=quote)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if an embed already exists in a list of stored embeds sent by my bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64040388/check-if-an-embed-already-exists-in-a-list-of-stored-embeds-sent-by-my-bot)

Comment: @nurqm that question is unanswered :((

Comment: Yes but you already ask that question, why did you posted the same question again?

Comment: Because no one answered :) @Nurqm

Comment: That's not an excuse to repost a question. You should wait for 2 days, if it's still unanswered, you should try to edit it or for the **last** option: deleting it.

Comment: What do you mean thats not an excuse lol thats a perfect reason to repost a question. @Nurqm

Comment: You cannot spam the same question just because your 5-hour question was not answered. You have to wait for answer. Sometimes it can be answered 1 week later, sometimes in 10 minutes.

Comment: Alright I will wait ~ 2days before asking next time. Sorry @Nurqm